# Ambiguous use of 'pow'

Tags: swift

Hi guys I tried to when someone give a second then get how much live in gigasecond. So I wrote like this code. I have to multiply second to 10^9 but I got error. Ambiguous use of 'pow'.

```
func gigaSecond( second: Int)-> Int {
    
    var gigasecond : Int
    gigasecond = second * Int(pow(10, 9))
    
   return gigasecond   
}
```

Comment: You said “divide”, but your code is multiplying. Are you trying to calculate the number of nanoseconds? In that case, you intended “multiply”, like your code is doing.

Comment: Your code works as-is if you change `10` to `10.0`, That simply change eliminates the error and allows the code to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use Double

```
pow(10.0, 9.0)
```

Or use an Int value directly

```
func gigaSecond( second: Int)-> Int {
    return second / 1_000_000_000
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please note:** The `pow()` function returns a `decimal` value.

And, to convert this `decimal` value to an `Int` value, one could simply think of either of the following two:

> 1. `Int(pow(x, y))` ... [i.e. direct `Decimal` to `Int` conversion]
> 2. `Int(Double(pow(x, y)))` ... [i.e. `Decimal` to `Double` to `Int` conversions, in one go]

Both of these, however, result in the same `Ambiguous use of 'pow'` error (screenshots below).

> 1. [image]
> 2. [image]

Interestingly, however, if we break the second option in two lines of code, that is: 
a) `Decimal to Double`, and then 
b) `Double to Int` 
...it works like a charm!

Here's the exact function you want without having to use a direct `Int` value (as desired):

```
func getGigaSeconds(from seconds: Int) -> Int {

    let gigaPower: Double = pow(10, 9)
    let gigaSeconds = seconds * Int(gigaPower)

    return gigaSeconds
}
```

**EDIT:** 
The Apple Developer documentation shows that the `y` parameter of the `pow()` function is an `Int`, while both `x` and the `return-type` are `Decimal`.
[image]

**CONCLUSION:** 
The following variations work:

```
// 1) `y` is a `Double`
let gigaSeconds = Int(pow(10, Double(9)))

// 2) `x` is a `Double`
let gigaSeconds = Int(pow(Double(10), 9))

// 3) Both, `x` and `y` are `Double`
let gigaSeconds = Int(pow(Double(10), Double(9)))

// 4) Both, `x` and `y` are `Int` but the end result is a `Double` (which is then converted to an `Int`
let gigaPower: Double = pow(10, 9)
let gigaSeconds = seconds * Int(gigaPower)
```

Comment: `Int(pow(x, y))` works just fine with no errors as long as `x` is a `Decimal` or `Double` and `y` is an `Int`. The OP's code works just fine with `Int(pow(10.0, 9))`.

Comment: Touchè, @HangarRash!  Or, as long as `y` is also a `Decimal` or a `Double`. That is, `Int(pow(10, 9.0)` also works fine. :)

Comment: Your edit is odd. You point out that the `y` parameter is an `Int` but the `x` parameter is `Decimal`. So why do you then suggest changing the `Int` parameter to a `Double` and leaving the `Decimal` parameter as an `Int`? Seems backwards. And why change `9` to `Double(9)` instead of to `9.0`?

Comment: Something that I tried and found to be working, I just wrote it as an 'Edit'.

Comment: FYI - All of these work somehow even though `x` is a `Decimal` and `y` is an `Int` : 
1. Int(pow(Double(10), Double(9)))
2. Int(pow(Double(10), 9))
3. Int(pow(10, Double(9)))

Comment: Re. the "seems backward" comment... If you note this code: `let gigaPower: Double = pow(10, 9)` ... both `x` and `y` are written as an `Int` (if you will) and yet it works absolutely fine. How's it that the `x` is being converted to `Decimal` or `Double` from an `Int` on its own?

Comment: And similarly, the end result, which should be a `Decimal` (func's return type) is converted to the desired `Double` type.